# Drupal dpm doesn't log anything on alter hook?

Tags: php, drupal

```
function user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'something something';

    dpm($form); //didn't do anything?
    var_dump($form); //printed something
}
```

`dpm($form);` doesn't print anything, any clue why? whereby `var_dump` worked in this case.

Comment: @Baas-B return means stop right? why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. `dpm()` and other `devel` functions require the current user to have `'access devel information'` permission to execute.

Since you need to trigger the user login form builder, it's likely you just log out whenever you try to debug it.

But in this case your user role is `'anonymous'` and you don't (and should never) have 'access devel information' permission.

Just build and return the form using `drupal_get_form()` from a page callback of yours so that you can debug it while staying logged in.